# Invalid argument when writing to a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to read from a binary file using pickle, adjust its contents and then overwrite the contents of the binary file with the new updated dictionary. 
However, I am receiving this error:

> startHandCountFile = open("startHandCount", 'wb') OSError: [Errno 22]
>   Invalid argument: 'startHandCount'.

My current understanding is that it should work as the file is located in the same directory as the python file that is being run and I have checked that I haven't miss spelt the file.

My code:

```
    startHandCountFile = open("startHandCount", "rb")
    self.startHandCount = pickle.load(startHandCountFile)
    self.currentStartHandCount = self.startHandCount
    self.startHandCount[startingTotal][1] += 1
    print("print still working")
    startHandCountFile.close()

    startHandCountFile = open("startHandCount", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(self.currentStartHandCount, startHandCountFile)
    startHandCountFile.close()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you using, per chance, some strange filesystem like MVFS (clearcase) ?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Not too familiar with MVFS however the directory is held in my dropbox. Would dropbox be considered an MVFS?

Comment: There are sync problems in those.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Thanks for the help. Just stored the files locally on my hard drive seemed to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried running my program outside of my dropbox and in a directory located on my hard drive which solved the error I was getting.